# ListFragment item not clickable. Content Provider and Custom Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter

I have this simple program that populates data using Content Provider and using Custom cursor adapter. My problem is that the item of the listfragment is not clickable even though the item has a `"android:textIsSelectable="true"`. I have done a debugging and i could see that `onListItemClick` is not called.

These are my XML

activity_item_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dream , Believe and Achieve!"
        android:id="@+id/achieveButton"    
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/believe"

        />


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:name="com.toksis.lawofattraction.ItemListFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" tools:context=".ItemListActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_item_detail"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment_item_detail.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/item_detail"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="16dp" android:textIsSelectable="true"
    tools:context=".ItemDetailFragment"
    />
```

ItemlistFragment Oncreate snippet.

```
// Create an array to specify the fields to display in the list
        // (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[] { WishContentProvider.COLUMN_WISH };
        // and an array of the fields to bind those fields to (in this
        // case, just text1)
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.item_detail };
        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display

 /*   mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0); */


    mAdapter = new WishCursorAdaptor(getActivity(),   

   getActivity().getContentResolver()
            .query(WishContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, from, null, null, null),
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Cursor adapter :WishCursorAdapter

```
    public class WishCursorAdaptor extends CursorAdapter {
    
    
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
    
        public WishCursorAdaptor(Context context, Cursor c,int autoRequry) {
            super(context, c,autoRequry);
    
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
    
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,parent,false);
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    
            TextView wish = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);
    
            wish.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("wish")));
    
        }
       }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to override the `onListItemClick` function. I can't see it anywhere in your code..

Comment: @Darpan  I have it. It is just autocreated in the AndroidStudio Master/Detail design.

Comment: @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }

Comment: The problem is that onListItemClick --> not called. I dont know why.

Comment: So what happens exactly? tried putting a Log.d("..","..); in onListItemClick? Also, you need to call 'super.onList....' at the end of the function, not in the very first line.

Comment: I had placed a toast and put the super on the last of the code. This works with the built in Master Detail plan when at that time the adapter used is the arrayAdapter.

Comment: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                DummyContent.ITEMS));

Answer (score 0):

This is how.

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Do your stuff.. 
    }

}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930624/609782)